# OpenMDAO add a<=X<=b constraint for constants a,b and array X

Tags: arrays, openmdao

I want to constrain (not bound) the `z` design variable so that each entry is constrained to be less that or equal to `5` and greater than or equal to `-5`: `-5<=Z<=5`. I attempt to do this by defining the constraint to just return the values of z (`self.add('con_cmp1', ExecComp('con1 = z'), promotes=['z', 'con1'])`) then defining the constraint to have an upper limit of `5.0` and a lower limit of `-5.0` (`top.driver.add_constraint('con1', lower=np.array([-5., -5.]), upper=np.array([5.,5.]))`).

When I do this, I get the error `Type <type 'numpy.ndarray'> of source 'pz.z' (z) must be the same as type <type 'float'> of target 'con_cmp1.z' (z)`. What does this error mean? How can I properly set this constraint?

```
from __future__ import print_function
from openmdao.api import ExecComp, IndepVarComp, Group, NLGaussSeidel, \
                         ScipyGMRES, Problem, ScipyOptimizer
import numpy as np

from openmdao.api import Component


class SellarDis1(Component):
    """Component containing Discipline 1."""

    def __init__(self):
        super(SellarDis1, self).__init__()

        # Global Design Variable
        self.add_param('z', val=np.zeros(2))

        # Local Design Variable
        self.add_param('x', val=0.)

        # Coupling parameter
        self.add_param('y2', val=1.0)

        # Coupling output
        self.add_output('y1', val=1.0)

    def solve_nonlinear(self, params, unknowns, resids):
        """Evaluates the equation
        y1 = z1**2 + z2 + x1 - 0.2*y2"""

        z1 = params['z'][0]
        z2 = params['z'][1]
        x1 = params['x']
        y2 = params['y2']

        unknowns['y1'] = z1**2 + z2 + x1 - 0.2*y2

    def linearize(self, params, unknowns, resids):
        """ Jacobian for Sellar discipline 1."""
        J = {}

        J['y1','y2'] = -0.2
        J['y1','z'] = np.array([[2*params['z'][0], 1.0]])
        J['y1','x'] = 1.0

        return J


class SellarDis2(Component):
    """Component containing Discipline 2."""

    def __init__(self):
        super(SellarDis2, self).__init__()

        # Global Design Variable
        self.add_param('z', val=np.zeros(2))

        # Coupling parameter
        self.add_param('y1', val=1.0)

        # Coupling output
        self.add_output('y2', val=1.0)

    def solve_nonlinear(self, params, unknowns, resids):
        """Evaluates the equation
        y2 = y1**(.5) + z1 + z2"""

        z1 = params['z'][0]
        z2 = params['z'][1]
        y1 = params['y1']

        # Note: this may cause some issues. However, y1 is constrained to be
        # above 3.16, so lets just let it converge, and the optimizer will
        # throw it out
        y1 = abs(y1)

        unknowns['y2'] = y1**.5 + z1 + z2

    def linearize(self, params, unknowns, resids):
        """ Jacobian for Sellar discipline 2."""
        J = {}

        J['y2', 'y1'] = .5*params['y1']**-.5

        #Extra set of brackets below ensure we have a 2D array instead of a 1D array
        # for the Jacobian;  Note that Jacobian is 2D (num outputs x num inputs).
        J['y2', 'z'] = np.array([[1.0, 1.0]])

        return J

class SellarDerivatives(Group):
    """ Group containing the Sellar MDA. This version uses the disciplines
    with derivatives."""

    def __init__(self):
        super(SellarDerivatives, self).__init__()

        self.add('px', IndepVarComp('x', 1.0), promotes=['x'])
        self.add('pz', IndepVarComp('z', np.array([5.0, 2.0])), promotes=['z'])

        self.add('d1', SellarDis1(), promotes=['z', 'x', 'y1', 'y2'])
        self.add('d2', SellarDis2(), promotes=['z', 'y1', 'y2'])

        self.add('obj_cmp', ExecComp('obj = x**2 + z[1] + y1 + exp(-y2)',
                                     z=np.array([0.0, 0.0]), x=0.0, y1=0.0, y2=0.0),
                 promotes=['obj', 'z', 'x', 'y1', 'y2'])

        self.add('con_cmp1', ExecComp('con1 = z'), promotes=['z', 'con1'])

        self.nl_solver = NLGaussSeidel()
        self.nl_solver.options['atol'] = 1.0e-12

        self.ln_solver = ScipyGMRES()

top = Problem()
top.root = SellarDerivatives()

top.driver = ScipyOptimizer()
top.driver.options['optimizer'] = 'SLSQP'
top.driver.options['tol'] = 1.0e-8

top.driver.add_desvar('z', lower=np.array([-10.0, 0.0]),
                     upper=np.array([10.0, 10.0]))
top.driver.add_desvar('x', lower=0.0, upper=10.0)

top.driver.add_objective('obj')
top.driver.add_constraint('con1', lower=np.array([-5., -5.]), upper=np.array([5.,5.]))

top.setup()

# Setting initial values for design variables
top['x'] = 1.0
top['z'] = np.array([5.0, 2.0])

top.run()

print("\n")
print( "Minimum found at (%f, %f, %f)" % (top['z'][0], \
                                         top['z'][1], \
                                         top['x']))
print("Coupling vars: %f, %f" % (top['y1'], top['y2']))
print("Minimum objective: ", top['obj'])
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The fundamental problem is that ExecComp assumes everything is scalar unless you tell it otherwise. So you can make the code you have work, if you give it some size information.

`self.add('con_cmp1', ExecComp('con1 = z', inits={'z':np.zeros(2), 'con1': np.zeros(2)}), promotes=['z', 'con1'])`

However, you don't actually needed the ExecComp at all. You can directly constraint the design variable like this:

`top.driver.add_constraint('z', lower=np.array([-5., -5.]), upper=np.array([5.,5.]))`